# Why do (semi-)conducting materials absorb microwaves at their cyclotron frequency? - Cyclotron Resonance Technique

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy, metals, experimental-technique

I am currently studying third year physics - more specifically a solid state course.

It was mentioned that in order to determine the effective mass of an electron in the nearly-free-electron model the cyclotron resonance technique can be used. 
"In a static magnetic field, an electron will move in a circular orbit with the cyclotron frequency(for 1T approx. microwave). A (semi)conducting material will therefore absorb microwaves at the the cyclotron frequency and the effective mass can be calculated."

**Why exactly does a conducting material absorb more or only absorb radiation at the cyclotron frequency?**

I could not find the answer in literature.

Comment: Because there are free carriers with relatively long lifetimes and scattering times, so an electron can sit there and 'orbit', absorbing microwave photons.

Comment: @JonCuster alright, so the electron will only absorb only very close to its cyclotron frequency. Is it right to call it a resonance frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. My solid state professor explained it the following way:

The electromagnetic waves will result in a force acting on the free electrons. This electromagnetic force acting on the electrons will oscillate with the frequency of the light. This results in the electrons absorbing the work done on them and gaining kinetic energy. Supposedly moving faster i. e. bigger circles. Note that the cyclotron frequency is independent of radius or velocity. The absorption of energy is highest because at the cyclotron frequency as it is the resonance frequency of these electrons.

Answer (score 0):

One can also imagine this quantum mechanically as a transition between individual  [Landau levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization). Then from the energy difference between two Landau levels cyclotron frequency will be:

$$  \omega_c = \frac{ e B}{m^*} $$

More details can be found, for example, in [Solid State Physics](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-73999-1) from John J. Quinn and Kyung-Soo Yi  (p. 395 - ...)